# Error MIDL 2025 when migration to Visual studio 2013 with ATL attributted?

Tags: c#, c++, com, migration, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in VS2005 - C++ ATL attributed COM - i try to migrate to VS2013 i get

```
error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification near "MyStruct"
```

1. The only option I found  to get project to compile is add a typdef the struct inside the interface. This causes the project to compile but any dependent project fail because of the redifinition of the struct.
2. On the dependant project C# I get the following `'MyStruct' is a 'type'`, which is not valid in the given context"

Is there a  place a place i can upload a full sulution ? (so any one could try)

Please advise

### The IDL of the first project COM C++

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";



[uuid("71C7F1BB-699B-4594-A2C0-88454F54C36A")]
struct MyStruct
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};
[
    uuid(CDEAA294-A77B-4703-A45A-C0001F126251),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring(" Cfc2_DataDictionary 1.0 Type Library")
]
library Cfc2_DataDictionary
{


    struct MyStruct;

    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
};
```

### The Interface with the error ATL Attributed COM C++

[
    object,
    uuid("15C5841B-4811-49F9-8961-C02240A6E0CF"),
    dual,   helpstring("IITransformMatrix Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]

```
__interface IITransformMatrix : IDispatch
{
    //remark next line to get error MIDL 2025
    typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;

    [helpstring("method Init")]

    HRESULT PutInverseMatrix([in] const MyStruct * matrix);
    HRESULT GetMatrix([out, retval]   MyStruct* matrix);

};
```

### The C# project which depend on both projects above

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Cfc2_DataDictionary;
using RnA_Utils;

    namespace Job.NET
    {


        public class WaferGeometry
        {
            public WaferGeometry(IITransformMatrix stmatrix)
            {
                myWaferGeometry = stmatrix;
                stmatrix.PutInverseMatrix(MyStruct);
            }
            private readonly IITransformMatrix myWaferGeometry;

        }
    }
```

Comment: "expecting a type specification near" - near what? Is this the full text of error message?

Comment: Sorry the full error is error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting a type specification near "MyStruct"

Comment: What if instead of typedef you make ([in] const struct MyStruct * matrix)? Will it compile?

Comment: Thanks But i cannot use const . get the following error Error C2259: 'ATL::CComObject<T>' : cannot instantiate abstract class